# KnockoutJS showing a sorted list by item category

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I just started learning knockout this week and everything has gone well except for this one issue.

I have a list of items that I sort multiple ways but one of the ways I want to sort needs to have a different display than the standard list. As an example lets say I have this code

```
var BetterListModel = function () {
var self = this;
food = [
{
    "name":"Apple",
    "quantity":"3",
    "category":"Fruit",
    "cost":"$1",
},{
    "name":"Ice Cream",
    "quantity":"1",
    "category":"Dairy",
    "cost":"$6",
},{
    "name":"Pear",
    "quantity":"2",
    "category":"Fruit",
    "cost":"$2",
},{
    "name":"Beef",
    "quantity":"1",
    "category":"Meat",
    "cost":"$3",
},{
    "name":"Milk",
    "quantity":"5",
    "category":"Dairy",
    "cost":"$4",
}];
self.allItems = ko.observableArray(food); // Initial items                                            
// Initial sort
self.sortMe = ko.observable("name");
ko.utils.compareItems = function (l, r) {
    if (self.sortMe() =="cost"){
        return l.cost > r.cost ? 1 : -1 
    } else if (self.sortMe() =="category"){
        return l.category > r.category ? 1 : -1
    } else if (self.sortMe() =="quantity"){
        return l.quantity > r.quantity ? 1 : -1
    }else {
        return l.name > r.name ? 1 : -1 
    }   

};
};
ko.applyBindings(new BetterListModel());
```

and the HTML

```
<p>Your values:</p>
<ul class="deckContents" data-bind="foreach:allItems().sort(ko.utils.compareItems)">
    <li><div style="width:100%"><div class="left" style="width:30px" data-bind="text:quantity"></div><div class="left fixedWidth" data-bind="text:name"></div> <div  class="left fixedWidth" data-bind="text:cost"></div> <div  class="left fixedWidth" data-bind="text:category"></div><div style="clear:both"></div></div></li>
</ul>
<select data-bind="value:sortMe">
    <option selected="selected" value="name">Name</option>
    <option value="cost">Cost</option>
    <option value="category">Category</option>
    <option value="quantity">Quantity</option>
</select>
</div>
```

So I can sort these just fine by any field I might sort them by name and it will display something like this

```
3 Apple $1 Fruit
1 Beef $3 Meat
1 Ice Cream $6 Dairy
5 Milk $4 Dairy
2 Pear $2 Fruit
```

Here is a fiddle of what I have so far http://jsfiddle.net/Darksbane/X7KvB/

This display is fine for all the sorts except the category sort. What I want is when I sort them by category to display it like this

```
Fruit
3 Apple $1 Fruit
2 Pear $2 Fruit

Meat
1 Beef $3 Meat

Dairy
1 Ice Cream $6 Dairy
5 Milk $4 Dairy
```

Does anyone have any idea how I might be able to display this so differently for that one sort?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Your view shouldn't contain logic beyond that necessary to render it. Thus, your `foreach` binding 
  `data-bind="foreach:allItems().sort(ko.utils.compareItems)"` should become a `computed` observable.
- You should move the `<option>` data into your model and take advantage of the `options` data-bind.

To address the actual question, you'll take advantage of `template` binding and `containerless` `if` binding.

The `template` binding will allow you to change the look/feel of the view based on the selected sort type. So 2 templates are available, the `default-template` which handles the regular display and the `category-template` specifically for category based rendering.

```
<script type="text/html" id="category-template">
 <ul class="deckContents" data-bind="foreach:sortedItems">
     <li>
         <!-- ko if: $root.outputCategory($index()) -->
         <div data-bind="text:category"></div>
         <!-- /ko -->
          <span class="indented" data-bind="text:name"></span> 
          <span  class="indented" data-bind="text:cost"></span> 
          <span  class="indented" data-bind="text:category"></span>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

The html usage: `<div data-bind='template: { name: currentTemplate, data: $data}'></div>` where `currentTemplate` is an computed observable that returns the template id based on sort type.

In some way or another you must assign priority to the categories. I have done this by declaring `var categoryPriority = ["Fruit", "Meat", "Dairy"]`.

Have a look at [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/KErRa/). *I didn't address the `fixedWidth` used by the `default-template` so you'll need to handle the CSS styling to line it up the way you want.*

**Edit**: *Is there a way to dynamically add an item to the list and have it show up in the sorted list automatically?*

1. Pushing a new item: When you want knockout to "notify" other elements then you don't want to `read` the observableArray by using `allItems()` before performing the push. Instead, you'll push into the observableArray using `allItems.push` which in-turn will cause knockout to trigger `computed observables` (that depend on this observable) to evaluate, `subscriptions` to execute, DOM elements to update ... etc.
2. Computed Dependencies: In order for a computed to "depend" on another observable it has to be `read` inside of the provided evaluator function. Since, `sortedItems` only reads `sortType` that is the only "trigger" for re-evaluation. Thus, changing the `allItems.sort` to `allItems().sort` causes `sortedItems` to evaluate whenever changes are made to `allItems`.

See [How Dependency Tracking Works](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)

Comment: thanks for the help. Is there a way to dynamically add an item to the list and have it show up in the sorted list automatically? I tried editing your fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Darksbane/Mt8FV/) and pushing an item to the self.allItems but the view doesn't update until the I change the sort again.

Comment: Added section detailing the necessary changes.

Answer (score 0):

By using sort method we can sort the list by ascending order.
I am taking your example and explain this.

```
food = [{
    "name":"Apple",
    "quantity":"3",
    "category":"Fruit",
    "cost":"$1",
},{
    "name":"Ice Cream",
    "quantity":"1",
    "category":"Dairy",
    "cost":"$6",
},{
    "name":"Pear",
    "quantity":"2",
    "category":"Fruit",
    "cost":"$2",
},{
    "name":"Beef",
    "quantity":"1",
    "category":"Meat",
    "cost":"$3",
},{
    "name":"Milk",
    "quantity":"5",
    "category":"Dairy",
    "cost":"$4",
}];
self.allItems = ko.observableArray(food);
```

Here you have an array. By using below code to sort this list

```
self.allItems.sort(function (left, right) {
    return left.name() == right.name() ? 0 : (left.name() < right.name() ? -1 : 1)
});
```

like wise if u want to sort by cost ..is the same..Replace name to cost..u will get it.